# Observable.fromPromise empty during unit testing

Tags: typescript, promise, jasmine, observable

`loadAdList$` is an Observable that taps into the `actions$` stream:

```
loadAdList$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<adActions.Load>(adActions.LOAD)
    .switchMap((action) => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(store.findAll('ad', action.payload)
        .then((ads) => {
          return new adActions.LoadSuccess(ads);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return new adActions.LoadFail(err);
        }));
    });
```

It works in the browser, there is no problem with it. However, I want to unit test it as well:

```
actions$ = hot('-a', { a: loadAction });
const storeResponse = Promise.resolve(mockAds);
const expected$ = cold('-c', { c: loadSuccessAction });

spyOn(store, 'findAll').and.returnValue(storeResponse);

expect(effects.loadAdList$).toBeObservable(expected$);
```

The test fails with the following:

```
Expected 

to deep equal 
    {"frame":10,"notification":{"kind":"N","value":{"payload":"[
    ...
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the `store.findAll` method returning a promise. This is based on the results of the following test:

```
.switchMap((action) => {
  // This test will pass
  return Observable.from([new adActions.LoadSuccess(mockAds)]);

  // This test will fail
  return Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(new adActions.LoadSuccess(mockAds)));

});
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve` always resolves asynchronously and the RxJS `TestScheduler` - which underpins `hot` and `cold` - uses virtual time and is synchronous. For this reason, I doubt promises can be used with marble diagram tests, but I could be wrong. At the very least, your test is going to have to be asynchronous and it's not clear whether it is or isn't.

Comment: If you want an asynchronous test runner, I strongly recommend blue-tape.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is bit unfortunate but there wasn't great way to make promise resolves synchronously under context of TestScheduler in Rx v5. For those reason, if Observable source started off from promise it won't work with marble testings and you have to create assertion differently by subscribing.

Check https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/701 / https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/745 if you'd like to have detail why it wasn't successful.

Comment: Although very understandable, it sucks. It basically means that if you use `from()` in any of your RXJS chains or NGRX `@effects`, you have to use mixed testing methods to write tests, because using Promises make marble testing impossible.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw you can always mock functions that return promises to return `of(...)`, though I appreciate this isn't always going to create the desired effect.

Comment: @hevans900 yes, of course, which is fine. but what if you want to test a complicated observable chain, that somewhere inside uses `from()`? There you go, you now can't use marble testing anymore. Also not a big problem, but the fact that you need to know that you can't, I'd say, ís.
in other words: imagine you don't want to test the outcome / result because it's used in a component or elsewhere, you want to test the observable chain itself.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw no, you can indeed marble test chains of Observables, with `from(somePromise)` in the middle, you just have to mock `somePromise` to return `of(...)`. I have it working here in front of me, happy to send you a github gist if you like. This works because the underlying implementation of `from` first type-checks the argument to see if it's an Observable, and avoids any conversion if so.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/from.ts#L111

Comment: I got bored and stripped down my current auth flow to a gist for you to demonstrate: https://gist.github.com/hevans90/9f999420806870f7201b7cd081cd1b6c#file-auth-effects-ts-L25. Hope this helps. NOTE: this was done with angular 9 RC8 - hence the `Testbed.inject`s.

Comment: @hevans900 I understand what you are saying, but I feel that you are not understanding what I'm saying :) In your example, `from(somePromise)` is a library method `this.oktaAuth.logout('/')` which you don't need to test (you depend on them to have tested their own implementation. In my case, I am not testing some third party code, but my own specific methods returning `Promises`. I actually need to test that the whole chain, including my own methods work. If I mock out the methods that return `Promise`s with Observables, I'm not testing them. Do you see what I mean? Thanks though!

Comment: I'd argue you are somewhat missing the point of marble testing. You WANT to mock out your dependencies because what you should be interested in is how your Observable stream reacts to meaningful data flowing through your pipeline of operators. You should NOT be trying to integration test hoards of actual observables/promises, as you'll get lost quickly. Asserting against the behaviour of your stream under different constraints is where marbles really starts to shine. Try writing more compositional functions where the behaviour can be tested in a box, and you'll run in to fewer of these issues.