# How to correctly test effects in ngrx 4?

Tags: testing, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

There are plenty of tutorials how to **test effects** in **ngrx 3**.

However, I've found only 1 or 2 for *ngrx4* (where they removed the classical approach via **EffectsTestingModule** ), e.g. [the official tutorial](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md)

However, in my case their approach doesn't work.

**effects.spec.ts** (under *src/modules/list/store/list* in the link below)

```
 describe('addItem$', () => {
    it('should return LoadItemsSuccess action for each item', async() => {
      const item = makeItem(Faker.random.word);
      actions = hot('--a-', { a: new AddItem({ item })});

      const expected = cold('--b', { b: new AddUpdateItemSuccess({ item }) });
      // comparing marbles
      expect(effects.addItem$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  })
```

**effects.ts** (under *src/modules/list/store/list* in the link below)

```
...
 @Effect() addItem$ = this._actions$
    .ofType(ADD_ITEM)
    .map<AddItem, {item: Item}>(action => {
      return action.payload
    })
    .mergeMap<{item: Item}, Observable<Item>>(payload => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this._listService.add(payload.item))
    })
    .map<any, AddUpdateItemSuccess>(item => {
      return new AddUpdateItemSuccess({
        item,
      })
    });
...
```

**Error**

```
 should return LoadItemsSuccess action for each item
        Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
        Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 20, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: AddUpdateItemSuccess({ payload: Object({ item: Object({ title: Function }) }), type: 'ADD_UPDATE_ITEM_SUCCESS' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
            at compare (webpack:///node_modules/jasmine-marbles/index.js:82:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:159059:33)
            at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/modules/list/store/list/effects.spec.ts:58:31 <- karma-test-shim.js:131230:42)
            at step (karma-test-shim.js:131170:23)
```

NOTE: the effects use a **service** which involves writing to PouchDB. However, the issue doesn't seem related to that
 and also **the effects work** in the running app.

The full code is a Ionic 3 app and be found [here](https://github.com/dragGH102/ionic-with-ngrx-and-multiple-modules) (just clone, npm i and **npm run test**)

**UPDATE**:

With **ReplaySubject** it works, but not with hot/cold marbles

```
  const item = makeItem(Faker.random.word);
  actions = new ReplaySubject(1) // = Observable + Observer, 1 = buffer size

  actions.next(new AddItem({ item }));

  effects.addItem$.subscribe(result => {
    expect(result).toEqual(new AddUpdateItemSuccess({ item }));
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

My question was answered by @phillipzada at the [Github issue I posted.](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/498)

### For anyone checking this out later, I report here the answer:

Looks like this is a RxJS issue when using promises using marbles. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313743/4148561

I did manage to do a bit of a hack which should work, however, you will need to put a separate test the service is being called unless you can update the service to return an observable instead of a promise.

Essentially what I did was extract the Observable.fromPromise call into its own "internal function" which we can mock to simulate a call to the service, then it looks from there.

This way you can test the internal function _addItem without using marbles.

**Effect**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export const ADD_ITEM = 'Add Item';
export const ADD_UPDATE_ITEM_SUCCESS = 'Add Item Success';

export class AddItem implements Action {
    type: string = ADD_ITEM;
    constructor(public payload: { item: any }) { }
}

export class AddUpdateItemSuccess implements Action {
    type: string = ADD_UPDATE_ITEM_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: { item: any }) { }
}

export class Item {

}

export class ListingService {
    add(item: Item) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(item); });
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class SutEffect {

    _addItem(payload: { item: Item }) {
        return Observable.fromPromise(this._listService.add(payload.item));

    }

    @Effect() addItem$ = this._actions$
        .ofType<AddItem>(ADD_ITEM)
        .map(action => action.payload)
        .mergeMap<{ item: Item }, Observable<Item>>(payload => {
            return this._addItem(payload).map(item => new AddUpdateItemSuccess({
                item,
            }));
        });

    constructor(
        private _actions$: Actions,
        private _listService: ListingService) {

    }
}
```

**Spec**

```
import { cold, hot, getTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getTestActions, TestActions } from 'app/tests/sut.helpers';

import { AddItem, AddUpdateItemSuccess, ListingService, SutEffect } from './sut.effect';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

describe('Effect Tests', () => {

    let store: Store<any>;
    let storeSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                StoreModule.forRoot({})
            ],
            providers: [
                SutEffect,
                {
                    provide: ListingService,
                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ListingService', ['add'])
                },
                {
                    provide: Actions,
                    useFactory: getTestActions
                }
            ]
        });

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
        storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();

    }));

    function setup() {
        return {
            effects: TestBed.get(SutEffect) as SutEffect,
            listingService: TestBed.get(ListingService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ListingService>,
            actions$: TestBed.get(Actions) as TestActions
        };
    }

    fdescribe('addItem$', () => {
        it('should return LoadItemsSuccess action for each item', async () => {

            const { effects, listingService, actions$ } = setup();
            const action = new AddItem({ item: 'test' });
            const completion = new AddUpdateItemSuccess({ item: 'test' });

            // mock this function which we can test later on, due to the promise issue
            spyOn(effects, '_addItem').and.returnValue(Observable.of('test'));

            actions$.stream = hot('-a|', { a: action });
            const expected = cold('-b|', { b: completion });

            expect(effects.addItem$).toBeObservable(expected);
            expect(effects._addItem).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });
    })

})
```

**Helpers**

```
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';

export class TestActions extends Actions {
    constructor() {
        super(empty());
    }
    set stream(source: Observable<any>) {
        this.source = source;
    }
}

export function getTestActions() {
    return new TestActions();
}
```