# Testing ng-rx effect with angular fire call

Tags: angular, promise, angularfire2, ngrx-effects

I'm working on a project using ng-rx and AngularFire. I'm using a custom token to sign in. Here is the code of the effect:

```
@Effect()
custom$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromAuthActions.AuthActionTypes.CustomTokenReceived),
    switchMap((action: fromAuthActions.CustomTokenReceived) => {
      return fromPromise(this.auth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(action.payload.token)).pipe(
        map((info: UserCredential) => new fromAuthActions.LoginSuccess()),
        tap(a => console.log(a)),
        catchError(error => of(new fromAuthActions.LoginFailed(error)))
      );
    })
  );
```

then I have a unit test for that effect:

```
....
const angularFireAuthStub = {
  auth: {
    signInWithCustomToken: jasmine.createSpy('signInWithCustomToken').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({dd: ''}))
  }
};
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    provideMockActions(() => actions),
    {provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: angularFireAuthStub},
    AuthEffects
  ],
});
....
it('should authorize on fb with custom token and return a login successful action', () => {
    const action = new fromActions.CustomTokenReceived({token: '12345'});
    const completion = new fromActions.LoginSuccess();

    actions = hot('-a', {a: action});
    const expected = cold('-b', {b: completion});

    expect(effects.custom$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
```

When running this I'm getting:

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
    Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: LoginSuccess({ type: '[Auth] Login Success' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
```

I've verified signInWithCustomToken return expected mocked value with the addition of the console.log call. I'm wondering why is is not detected on the toBeObservable expectation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like is not possible to test `fromPromise` using marbles [Observable.fromPromise empty during unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106985/observable-frompromise-empty-during-unit-testing)

So I've changes my test to:

```
it('should authorize on fb with custom token and return a login successful action', () => {
    const action = new fromActions.CustomTokenReceived({token: '12345'});
    const completion = new fromActions.LoginSuccess();

    actions = hot('-a', {a: action});

    effects.custom$.subscribe(r => expect(r).toEqual(completion));
  });
```